# myrecv function gSoap

Tags: c++, gsoap

I am trying to write a gSoap server, which needs to save the incoming message.  I want to save it in a buffer.  Here is how gSoap Documentation does it on a client side to save the outgoing message...

```
//from gSoap Documentation 
//SOURCE: https://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.7
int mysend(struct soap *soap, const char *s, size_t n)
{
   struct buffer *h = (struct buffer*)soap->user; // get buffer through handle
   int m = h->max, k = h->len + n;
   // need to increase space?
   if (m == 0)
      m = 1024;
   else 
      while (k >= m)
         m *= 2;
   if (m != h->max)
   {
      char *buf = malloc(m);
      memcpy(buf, h->buf, h->len);
      h->max = m;
      if(h->buf)
         free(h->buf);
      h->buf = buf;
   }
   memcpy(h->buf + h->len, s, n);
   h->len += n;
   return SOAP_OK;
}
```

this works with some modification, but if I take this same idea to the server side, store to a buffer and end it with this return statement...

```
size_t myrecv(struct soap *soap, char *s, size_t n){
//do similar to above example...
...
return default_frecv(soap,s,n);
}
```

it only stores the message going from the server back to the client.  I need to save the message coming to the server from the client.  I thought recv would give me the incoming message, but this is not the case. Any Ideas?   Any help, suggestions, or ideas are appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

source to the mysend example: https://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.7

Answer (score 0):

> I need to save the message coming to the server from the client. I
>   thought recv would give me the incoming message, but this is not the
>   case.

Hmmm. The documentation clearly says that `frecv()` is the callback that receives all messages, regardless whether it is the client side implementation or the server side implementation. So defining your own `frecv()` callback should so it. If you get stuck, take a look at the gsoap/plugin/logging.c message logger that implements this callback to capture the message received and sends it to a file/pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hook into frecv() and do my own additional processing after invoking the default frecv() function.  However, a new purpose requires me to parse the buffer before the default frecv(), at which point it doesn't yet exist.  Once the default frecv() is called, the buffer exists, but the action taken on the buffer (namely soap_serve()), which I wanted to intercept, has already occurred, so I'm one request behind in my derived context.

My intent was to parse the buffer for the name of the WSDL, in order to assign a unique namespace to soap_serve(), but it's not working.